# Follow a post so I can read any new answer

Tags: support

I would like to know how I can follow a post so I can read any new answers concerning this post.

Comment: One way is to "bookmark" it by clicking the star on the left.  Then you'll find it among your [favourites](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19795/bendesarts?tab=favorites), so you can come back to check later.  Your profile page will display the number of new events that happened on favourites since the last time you checked them. It's the blue number on the favourites tab. But you still need to check manually.  Sorry, I don't know of a better way.

Comment: There could be a different solution on [Stackapps](http://stackapps.com/).

Answer (score 4):

For your *own* questions there is a check-box **Send me new responses to my posts via email** (with settings) that should do this.  I cannot recall a similar mechanism for other people's questions *besides* the use of **Favorites** as Szabolcs [describes above](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/follow-a-post-so-i-can-read-any-new-answer#comment6865_1659).

Answer (score 4):

You could check the number of answers and the last activity date using the [stackexchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/)

List of questions Id

```
qidl = {4294, 52393, 559};

query[ql_List] := Import[URLBuild[
   {
    "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions"
    , StringRiffle[ToString /@ ql, ";"]
    }
   , {
    "order" -> "desc"
    , "sort" -> "activity"
    , "site" -> "mathematica"
    , "filter" -> "!4(Yr-N6OsqLj7HtTQ"
    }
   ], "JSON"]

query[qidl]
```

> {"quota_remaining" -> 280
>       , "quota_max" -> 300
>       , "items" -> {
>         {
>          "answer_count" -> 3
>          , "link" -> "[How to make use of Associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations)"
>          , "last_activity_date" -> 1439340460
>          , "question_id" -> 52393
>         }, {"answer_count" -> 7, 
>           "link" -> 
>            "[What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-)\
>       use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs", 
>           "last_activity_date" -> 1431677762, "question_id" -> 559}}, 
>        "has_more" -> False}